# ¿Por qué se ordenan 2 arreglos de distinta clase al mismo tiempo?

Tags: java, ordenamiento

Tengo un arreglo instanciado en mi clase `PlanificationAlgorithms` donde guardo los datos a mandar como argumentos a los métodos pertenecientes a la clase «Algoritmos» donde los asigno a un arreglo local perteneciente a su clase. 
Mi pregunta va enfocada a entender el porqué cuando ejecuto el código:`Arrays.sort(cola)` se ordena no sólo el array local, sino que también se ordena el array que pertenece a la clase `PlanificationAlgorithms`.

Clase `PlanificationAlgorithms`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

class PlanificationAlgorithms{

   public static void main (String args[]){
   /**
      * Datos de prueba.
      98
      183
      37
      122
      14
      124
      65
      67
   */

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Algoritmos alg = new Algoritmos();
      int opc = 0, nDatos, cabezal;
      boolean encontrado = false;

      try{
         do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de datos a agregar a la cola: ");
            nDatos = sc.nextInt();
         } while (nDatos > 200 || nDatos < 0);
         int datos[] = new int[nDatos]; // Declaración del arreglo.
         System.out.println("Lectura de los datos...");      
         for (int i = 0; i < nDatos; i++){
            datos[i] = sc.nextInt();
         }
         System.out.println("¿Desea modificar el numero de cilindros? \n(Default 200)\n[1] - Si.\n[2] - No.");
         int cilindros = sc.nextInt();
         if (cilindros == 1){
            cilindros = sc.nextInt();
         } else if (cilindros == 2){
            cilindros = 200;
         }
         do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del cabezal: ");
            cabezal = sc.nextInt();
            encontrado = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < nDatos; i++){
               if(cabezal == datos[i])
                  encontrado = true;
               break;
            }
         } while (cabezal > 200 || encontrado == true || cabezal < 0);

         do{
            System.out.println("\n\n\n-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("            MENU");
            System.out.println("[1] - FCFS.");
            System.out.println("[2] - SSTF.");
            System.out.println("[3] - SCAN.");
            System.out.println("[4] - C.SCAN.");
            System.out.println("[5] - LOOK.");
            System.out.println("[6] - C.LOOK.");
            System.out.println("[7] - Salir.");
            opc = sc.nextInt();
            switch(opc){
               case 1:
                  alg.FCFS(datos, cabezal);
                  break;
               case 2:
                  alg.SSTF(datos,cabezal);
                  break;
               case 3:
                  alg.SCAN(datos,cabezal);
                  break;
               case 4:
                  alg.C_SCAN(datos,cabezal);
                  break;
               case 5:
                  alg.LOOK(datos,cabezal);
                  break;
               case 6:
                  alg.C_LOOK(datos,cabezal);
                  break;
            }
         } while (opc != 7);
         System.out.println("Cya");
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
         System.out.print(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Clase `Algoritmos`:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Algoritmos{
   private int cola[];
   /**
      * Datos de prueba.
      98
      183
      37
      122
      14
      124
      65
      67
   */

   /**
      * Método FCFS - Algoritmo First Come First Served.
      *
      * Atiende al primero en llegar.
      *
      * @param datos[] es un arreglo con los datos de la cola.
      * @param cabezal es la posición inicial del cabezal por el cuál empezará a trabajar el algoritmo.
   */

   public void FCFS (int datos[], int cabezal){

      int tabla[][] = new int[datos.length][4];

      for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++){
         if (i == 0){
            tabla[i][0] = cabezal;
            tabla[i][1] = datos[i];
            tabla[i][2] = 0;
            tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][1] - tabla[i][0]);
         } else {
            tabla[i][0] = tabla[i - 1][1];
            tabla[i][1] = datos[i];
            tabla[i][2] = (tabla[i - 1][2] + tabla[i - 1][3]);
            tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][1] - tabla[i][0]);
         }
      }
      print(tabla);
   }

   /**
      * Método SSTF - Algoritmo Shortest Seek Time First.
      *
      * Se atiende la solicitud con el menor tiempo de búsqueda desde la posición actual de las cabezas.
      *
      * @param datos[] es un arreglo con los datos de la cola.
      * @param cabezal es la posición inicial del cabezal por el cuál empezará a trabajar el algoritmo.
   */

   public void SSTF (int datos[], int cabezal){
      cola = datos;
      int tabla[][] = new int[cola.length][4];
      Arrays.sort(cola); // Primer ordenamiento.
      int tamano = cola.length;
      int loop = 0;
      int menorDistancia = 0, indice = 0, distancia = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++){
         if (i == 0){
            tabla[i][0] = cabezal;
            for (int j = 0; j < tamano - 1; j++){
               if (Math.abs(cola[j] - cabezal) > Math.abs(cola[j + 1] - cabezal)){
                  menorDistancia = cola[j + 1];
                  indice = j + 1;
               }
            }
            cola[indice] = 0;
            Arrays.sort(cola); // Ordenamiento.
            loop++;
            tabla[i][1] = menorDistancia;
            tabla[i][2] = 0;
            tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][1] - tabla[i][0]);
         } else {
            tabla[i][0] = tabla[i - 1][1];
            distancia = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = loop; j < tamano ; j++){
               if (Math.abs(cola[j] - tabla[i][0]) < distancia){
                  menorDistancia = cola[j];
                  distancia = Math.abs(cola[j] - tabla[i][0]);
                  indice = j;
               } 
            }
            cola[indice] = 0;
            Arrays.sort(cola); // Ordenamiento.
            loop++;
            tabla[i][1] = menorDistancia;
            tabla[i][2] = (tabla[i - 1][2] + tabla[i - 1][3]);
            tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][1] - tabla[i][0]);
         }
      }
      print(tabla); 
   }

   public void SCAN (int datos[], int cabezal){

      int tabla[][] = new int[datos.length][4];
      cola = datos;
      boolean encontrado = false;
      int cont = 0, primero = 0;
      Arrays.sort(cola); // Ordenamiento.

      for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; ){
         if (i == 0){
            tabla[i][0] = cabezal;
            while (encontrado == false){
               if (datos[cont] > cabezal){
                  tabla[i][1] = datos[cont];
                  tabla[i][2] = 0;
                  tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][0] - tabla[i][1]);
                  primero = cont;
                  encontrado = true;
               }
               cont++;
            }
            i++;
         } else {
            while (cont != datos.length){
               tabla[i][0] = tabla[i - 1][1];
               tabla[i][1] = datos[cont];
               tabla[i][2] = (tabla[i - 1][2] + tabla[i - 1][3]);
               tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][0] - tabla[i][1]);
               cont++;
               i++;
            }
            while (primero > 0){
               primero--;
               tabla[i][0] = tabla[i - 1][1];
               tabla[i][1] = datos[primero];
               tabla[i][2] = (tabla[i - 1][2] + tabla[i - 1][3]);
               tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][0] - tabla[i][1]);
               cont++;
               i++;
            }
         }
      }
      print(tabla); 
   }

   public void C_SCAN (int datos[], int cabezal){
      int tabla[][] = new int[datos.length][4];
      boolean encontrado = false;
      int cont = 0, primero = 0;
      Arrays.sort(datos); // Ordenamiento.

      for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; ){
         if (i == 0){
            tabla[i][0] = cabezal;
            while (encontrado == false){
               if (datos[cont] > cabezal){
                  tabla[i][1] = datos[cont];
                  tabla[i][2] = 0;
                  tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][0] - tabla[i][1]);
                  primero = cont;
                  encontrado = true;
               }
               cont++;
            }
            i++;
         } else {
            while (cont != datos.length){
               tabla[i][0] = tabla[i - 1][1];
               tabla[i][1] = datos[cont];
               tabla[i][2] = (tabla[i - 1][2] + tabla[i - 1][3]);
               tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][0] - tabla[i][1]);
               cont++;
               i++;
            }
            int aux = 0;
            while (encontrado == true){
               if (datos[aux] < cabezal){
                  tabla[i][0] = tabla[i - 1][1];
                  tabla[i][1] = datos[aux];
                  tabla[i][2] = (tabla[i - 1][2] + tabla[i - 1][3]);
                  tabla[i][3] = Math.abs(tabla[i][0] - tabla[i][1]);
                  i++;
               } else {
                  encontrado = false;
               }
               aux++;
            }
         }
      }
      print(tabla);
   }

   public void LOOK (int datos[], int cabezal){

   }

   public void C_LOOK (int datos[], int cabezal){

   }
   /**
      * Método print.
      * @param tabla[][] es el arreglo a imprimir.
   */
   public void print(int tabla[][]){
      System.out.printf("%-10S %25S %25S %25S","Pos. Inicial", "Cilindro Solicitado", "Tiempo Espera", "Desplazamiento\n");
      float promedioEspera = 0.2f;
      for (int i = 0; i < tabla.length; i++) {
         System.out.printf("%-10d %17d %30d %25d", tabla[i][0], tabla[i][1], tabla[i][2], tabla[i][3]);
         promedioEspera = promedioEspera + tabla[i][2];
         System.out.println("");
      }
      System.out.println("\n\nEl tiempo de espera promedio es de " + promedioEspera / tabla.length);
   }
}
```

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta que los arreglos en Java son objetos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ¿Por qué se ordenan 2 arreglos de distinta clase al mismo tiempo?

**Respuesta:** No.

Los dos arreglos no se ordenan al mismo tiempo, debido a que, todo se está ejecutando de manera sincronizada (un proceso se ejecuta a la vez).

Y todo esto lo comprobamos en esta línea de código:

```java
alg.SSTF(datos,cabezal);
```

El identificador `datos` en realidad es un [puntero](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Punteros) (es una variable que almacena una dirección de memoria de un dato) que apunta a la dirección base (del primer atributo) de un objeto de tipo `int[]`, esto quiere decir, que en realidad lo que se le está pasando al parámetro `datos` (del método `SSTF`) es la dirección de memoria del primer atributo del objeto `int[]`. Entonces el parámetro `datos` del método `SSTF` apuntará al mismo objeto que apunta el puntero `datos` (del método `main`).

Posteriormente, se ejecuta esta instrucción:

```java
cola = datos;
```

Básicamente el puntero/parámetro `datos` le está asignando su contenido (una dirección de memoria) al puntero/variable `cola`. Por lo tanto, ambos punteros apuntarán al mismo objeto. Esto quiere decir que cuando el método `Arrays.sort(cola)` se ejecute, ordenará los elementos del objeto de tipo `int[]` al que apunte `datos` (del método `main`), debido a que, ambas variables están apuntando al mismo objeto.

Si no quieres que ambos punteros apunten a la misma dirección base del objeto de tipo `int[]`, necesitarás usar el método [copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) para poder tener un nuevo objeto de tipo `int[]` con una copia de los datos del objeto anterior.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
cola = Arrays.copyOf(datos, datos.length);
```

De este modo, los punteros `datos` y `cola` apuntarán a objetos diferentes. Así que al momento de ordenar los datos del objeto al que  apunte `cola`, no afectará el objeto  al que apunte `datos` (del método `main`).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Había olvidado por completo que esa línea de código hacia que apuntará a una dirección de memoria